# Cannot navigate/use a nested child route/outlet using Angular 2+ Router

Tags: angular

Does anybody know how i might use the otherdashboard and otherdashboardsidebar outlets using @angular/router. Here are my routes. I want to use hierarchical or nested routes so that breadcrumbing can be used.

```
export const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: MainComponent, data:{displayName:'My App Name'},
    children: [
      { path: 'mainDashboard', component: HomeComponent, outlet: 'content', data:{displayName:'First Dashboard'},
        children:[
          { path: 'otherdashboardsidebar', component: OtherDashboardSidebarComponent, outlet: 'sidebars' },
          { path: 'otherdashboard', component: OtherDashboardComponent, outlet: 'contents',data:{displayName:'Second Dashboard'} }
        ]},
    ]
  }
];
```

When i use

```
this.router.navigate(['/maindashboard',{outlets: {'content': ['otherdashboard'], 'sidebar': ['otherdashboardsidebar']}}]);
```

I get **Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'maindashboard'**

Comment: Did you try /dashboard/mainDashboard? That's the path you have specified in your routes.

Comment: I did. I just get Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'dashboard'